# How to keep scope within an XHR request?

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest, url-routing

So I am building a Javascript router and building a route like this:

```
route('/user/{name}', 'page', function() {
    this.text = 'User: ' + this.name;
});
```

The scope of the function is the current route, so I can manipulate the current route here (this.text is what the view is looking for).

Now my next step is to include an XHR request within the route, which would look something like:

```
route('/user/{name}', 'page', function() {
    this.text = 'Loading';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/api/user', true);

    request.onreadystatechange = (function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                // here is the issue: 'this' now refers to
                // the XHR request and not the scope of the router
                this.age = data.age;
                this.gender = data.gender;
            } else {
                this.text = "Error";
            }
        }
    })/* .bind(this); */ // keeping scope like this overwrites the XHR

    request.send();
    request = null;
});
```

The issue here is that I need to access the XHR scope *and* my router's scope. Using .bind at the end of the onreadystatechange would over write the XHR scope, and not setting it overwrites the router's scope.

so wat do? Is there anything cleaner than `var that = this;` -- surely there must be a way?

Comment: Cant' you just remove the `this` from `this.age` and `this.gender` ?

Comment: Why not: `var that = this;`? It may not be the most elegant way, but it works...

Comment: That is just my question, is there a cleaner way to keep the scope. Buuut I guess there is no way to avoid it since 'this' will class with 'this', perhaps a solution would be a way to set the default scope variable. Thanks @ChrisL and maze-le though.

Comment: @ChrisL nope, it would report that "age" / "gender" is not defined. The controller function is being called with something like:  `route.controller.apply(data);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (and very clear way) is to keep the reference to route's scope like this:

```
var that = this;
```

Also you can set the scope using `.bind()` and access request properties directly from `reqest` variable.

And for your example (with `bind` helper function, to support old browsers):

```
var bind = function(fn, context) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(context, arguments);
    };
};

request.onreadystatechange = bind(function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      this.age = data.age;
      this.gender = data.gender;
    } else {
      this.text = "Error";
    }
  }
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the cleanest way is to change the scope variable.. I really like your example (personally I prefer keeping scope and variable names consistent so this is why I went down this route), but it's really only supported in Chrome?

Comment: Oh, sorry... I have confused ES5 `bind` with Object.observe binding from ES7 proposals. It was just a quick look to the http://caniuse.com/#search=bind

Comment: Thanks for confirming :P I thought perhaps you were referring to the `fn.apply(content, arguments)` line as my mdn gave thumbs up all around really: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
route('/user/{name}', 'page', function() {
    var routeScope = this;

    request.onreadystatechange = (function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                console.log(this);
                // "this" is xhr's scope, while 
                console.log(routeScope);
                // routeScope is your router's scope
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
})
```

edit: err, just read your last sentence... nevermind.

Comment: Yeep, I could do that, and probably will. It's mainly just consistency across scopes. Thanks though.